# Advanced find and replace text in photoshop

Tags: script, adobe-photoshop

In photoshop, let's say I have a few texts layers with contents like this:

Text layer 1:  1@@text01@@abc
Text layer 2:  2@@text02@@cef
Text layer 3:  3@@text03@@hgi
I would like to replace all the layers texts starting with the first@ and the end @, that is "@@text..@@" to "##, 
so that results will be: 
**Text layer 1:  1##abc

Text layer 2:  2##cef

Text layer 3:  3##hgi**

I know that photoshop has the "find and replace" function, but it seems only to replace a string/text in a simple way. That's why I would like to know if there is a photoshop script that can do this in a quick way.

Thank you.